# Change a text between two strings in Python with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I found several similar questions, but I cannot fit my problem to any of them. I try to find and replace a string between two other strings in a text.

```
reg = "%s(.*?)%s" % (str1,str2)
r = re.compile(reg,re.DOTALL)
result = r.sub(newstring, originaltext)
```

The problem is that the code above replace also `str1` and `str2`, whereas I want to replace only the text between them. Something obviously that I miss?

**Update:**

I simplified example:

```
text = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

str1 = 'gh'
str2 = 'op'

newstring = 'stackexchange'

reg = "%s(.*?)%s" % (str1,str2)
r = re.compile(reg,re.DOTALL)
result = r.sub(newstring, text)

print result
```

The result is `abcdefstackexchangeqrstuvwxyz` whereas I need `abcdefghstackexchangeopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: It would be great if you can share some samples.

Comment: post the input and the expected output.

Comment: Done! I have added a simplified example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a combination of [lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround) in your regular expression.

```
reg = "(?<=%s).*?(?=%s)" % (str1,str2)
```

**Explanation**:

Lookarounds are zero-width assertions. They don't consume any characters on the string.

```
(?<=    # look behind to see if there is:
  gh    #   'gh'
)       # end of look-behind
.*?     # any character except \n (0 or more times)
(?=     # look ahead to see if there is:
  op    #   'op'
)       # end of look-ahead
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/169213)

Comment: Great! That works! I have to wait 2min more to choose it as best answer. Thank you