# Replace part of a string with values from CSV, save all values in CSV PYTHON

Tags: python, json, api, csv, bigdata

I have a list of a million pins and one URL that has a pin within the URL

Example:

https://www.example.com/api/index.php?pin=101010&key=113494

I have to change the number "101010" for the pin with the list of a million values like 093939,493943,344454 that I have in a csv file and then save all of those new urls to a csv file.

Here's what I have tried doing so far that has not worked:

```
def change(var_data):
  var = str(var_data)
  url = 'https://www.example.com/api/index.php?pin=101010&key=113494'
  url1 = url.split('=')
  url2 = ''.join(url1[:-2] + [var] + [url1[-1]])
  print(url2)

change('xxxxxxxxxx')
```

Also this is for an api request that goes to a json page. Would using python and then reiterating through these urls I save on a csv file be the best way to do this? I want to collect some information for all of the pins that I have and save it to a BigQuery database, or somewhere where I can connect to Google Data Studio in order to have the ability to create a dashboard using all of this data.

Any ideas? What do you think the best way of getting this done would be?

Comment: I recommend breaking this question up into two separate questions. First, how do you read , transform, and write to a csv? Second, questions about best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first part of the question, the changes to the `change` function returns a list of urls using f-strings.

This can then be applied via list comprehension.

The variable `url_variables` would be the list of integers for the variable you are reading in from the other file.

Then writing the url list to rows in a csv.

```
import csv

url_variables = [93939, 493943, 344454]

def change(var_data):
    var_data = str(var_data)
    url = 'https://www.example.com/api/index.php?pin='
    key = 'key=113494'
    new_url = f'{url}{var_data}&{key}'  
    return(new_url)

url_list = [change(x) for x in url_variables]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for val in url_list:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

Output in output.csv

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First part of the question: (replace the numbers between "pin=" and "&") I will use an answer from [Change a text between two strings in Python with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558361/change-a-text-between-two-strings-in-python-with-regex) post:

```
import re

def change(var_data):
  var = str(var_data)
  url = 'https://www.example.com/api/index.php?pin=101010&key=113494'
  url2 = re.sub("(?<=pin=).*?(?=&)",var,url)
  
  print(url2)

change('xxxxxxxxxx')
```

Here I use the sub method from the built-in package "re" and the RegEx Lookarounds sintax, where:

```
(?<=pin=)   # Asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is "pin="

.*? # is the occurrence of any character

(?=&) #Asserts that what immediately follows the current position in the string is "&"
```

Here is a [formal explanation about the Lookarounds syntax](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

**2.** Second part of the question:  As another answer explains, you can register the urls in the csv file by rows but I recommend you to read [this](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) post about handling csv files with python and you can give yourself an idea of ​​the way you want to save them.

I am not very good at english but I hope that I have explained myself well.